# Fitness equipment for back muscles

Tags: muscle-recovery, back-pain

I used to go this gym which had an equipment for back muscles training. The equipment helped me get rid of horrendous back pain I had for several years.

I am looking to buy one of these for myself but I don't know the name. Could someone please tell me the name and possibly refer me to a photo/website that shows one of those.

This is a sketch of the equipment.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the exercise is commonly referred to as a "back raise", and is done on a pretty rudimentary piece of equipment.

Here are some you can buy on eBay: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/back-extension-bench

At some point, you might feel the need to add resistance, so you could incorporate holding some weight plates, or something equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for both the answer and the advise for using weight.